# Freezing the left most column in a SharePoint list

Tags: office-365, custom-list, navigation

In an Office 365 installation, is there anyone that has found away to freeze the left most column of a custom list.

I have javascript for the headers, but for a list with many columns it would be great to keep the first column stationary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following Post which describes a technique to freeze the first column of a HTML table and then use the same CSS technique in your list through JS Link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a